# getting trouble in capturing image through cam and opencv in windows 8

Tags: c, opencv, camera, capture

I have first started getting images through the cam on a windows 7 basis and it worked fine; recently I have upgraded the OS with Windows 8 and that I think is the problem. The code is simple:

```
cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1);    
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
IplImage* frame;
while (1){
  frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
  cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame);      
  key = cvWaitKey(10);     
  if (char(key) == 27){
    break;
  }
}
```

and this gives only white noise through a window screen and a grey image if I save a part of the stream.

Any alternative functions to capture images in Windows 8 or advice would be helpful.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.2 with VS2010 and OpenCV 2.4.8 with VS2013, on Windows 8 64-bit.

Comment: Try to use new [C++ interface](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) instead deprecated c.

Comment: Make sure it did extract the frame from the capture. Double check it by adding `if (!frame) /* no frame captured! */`.

Comment: Make sure you are linking correct version of opencv with corresponding visual studio version. Also add error checks to see if the `capture` is NULL or not.